# Convertir String a Boolean, me genera error

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim condicion As String
    Dim cond As Boolean
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    a = 25
    b = 0
    condicion = "a >= 20 And b <= 50"
    cond = Convert.ToBoolean(condicion)
    If cond Then
        b = a
    End If
    Console.Out.WriteLine(a)
    Console.Out.WriteLine(b)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Tengo la siguiente pregunta, tengo una variable String:

```
Dim condicion As String = "a >= 20 And b <= 50"
```

Quisiera poder convertirlo a boolean para poder usarlo en un if y no encuentro la manera de poder hacerlo, seria de mucha ayuda, gracias, ya probe con Convert.ToBoolean(condicion) y me sale error aun, gracias

Comment: Sub Main()
        Dim condicion As String
        Dim cond As Boolean
        Dim a As Integer
        Dim b As Integer
        a = 25
        b = 0
        condicion = "a >= 20 And b <= 50"
        cond = Convert.ToBoolean(condicion)
        If cond Then
            b = a
        End If
        Console.Out.WriteLine(a)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(b)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

Basicamente si lo pongo directo en boolean no me da error, pero quisiera que de string pase a boolean, por favor

Comment: Ya le puse una imagen, ojala que alguien  me ayude

Comment: Bryan!, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada**, saludos!

Comment: Ya esta mejor creo yo o aun no?

Comment: @bryan puedes echar un vistazo a mi respuesta, para algo tan sencillo como lo que pones en tu ejemplo podría servirte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede.

`Convert.ToXXX` lo que hace es transformar un tipo de variable en otro tipo de variable.

Lo que vos estas tratando de hacer es interpretar un codigo en tiempo de ejecucion, y VB (ni c#) esta preparado para eso.

`Javascript` si lo hace, con la instrucción `Eval`.

para mas referencias mira la [pagina de Convert.ToBoolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Y habria alguna manera de poder hacerlo en visual de lo que pretendo hacer a parte del Convert.To?

Comment: no. no se pueden interpretar cadenas como codigo en tiempo de ejecucion. Si supieramos mas sobre lo que queres hacer, tal vez existiria (muy potencial) alguna forma.

Comment: En si voy a solicitar escribir una condicion, por ejemplo "a=50" , lo guardaria en un String supongo, y en base a la condicion que he escrito poder usarla , pero no encuentro manera de hacerlo

Comment: tu pregunta es mas compleja de lo que vos pensas. La pregunta seria para conseguir que cosa?

Comment: Es que basicamente me han pedido que lea una condicion, que la guarde y que la pueda usar, por eso puse ese ejmplo, pero la unica manera creo yo seria guardando la condicion en un String y luego convertirla a un boolean, tal vez la manera que pienso hacerlo no se pueda y por eso hice esa pregunta, tu de casualidad no sabrias alguna idea de como hacerlo para investigar, porque ya busque un poco de informacion y no encuentro algo parecido

Comment: dejaré esto por aquí: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/codedom-calculator-evaluating-C-Sharp-math-expressions-dynamica/ :)

Comment: deberias escribir un interprete.que lea la cadena y la sepa interpretar. algo bastante complejo.

Comment: muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: de nada @bryan. Recuerda siempre aceptar una respuesta si te sirvio.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque la respuesta de @gbianchi es correcta, voy a dar en la mia una alternativa que es tal vez poco conocida y que para cosas sencillas puede servir.

Se trata de utilizar [`DataTable.Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx), que evalúa una condicion pasada como string.

Esto lo combinamos con la interpolación de cadenas (uso en este caso la que proporciona C# a partir de la versión 6, y VB.net desde la 14, en las anteriores debemos usar `String.Format`).

Así quedaría tu código:

```
Dim condicion As String
Dim cond As Boolean
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
a = 25
b = 0
condicion As String = $"{a} >= 20 and {b} <= 50"
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
cond = dt.Compute(condicion, Nothing)
If cond Then
    b = a
End If
Console.Out.WriteLine(a)
Console.Out.WriteLine(b)

Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Esta casi que deberia ser la respuesta aceptada, aunque es una funcionalidad no documentada.

Comment: @gbianchi [Si está documentada](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_Compute_System_String_System_String_) :)